# glGetShaderInfoLog returns empty string, but shader program is not linked correctly

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

After linking my shader program, I get `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` when invoking `glGetUniformLocation`. The docs tell me that this means my shader program doesn't exist, or it has not been successfully linked.

But a call to `glGetShaderInfoLog` does not return any errors, it just returns an empty string (on OpenTK).

How can I find out what's wrong?

Comment: It is not required to return anything, although it would be tremendously helpful. Are you checking `GL_LINK_STATUS` through `glGetProgramiv (...)` - that is actually the correct way to determine whether a program linked correctly. Check that value after attempting to link the program or calling `glValidateProgram (...)`.

Comment: Calling `glGetProgramiv` with `GL_LINK_STATUS` returns `GL_FALSE`. But this doesn't really help, I already knew the program wasn't linked correctly. Still wondering why there is no log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. The reason were several `varying`s and `uniform`s that did not specify a precision qualifier:

```
varying vec4 vPosition;
```

instead of

```
varying lowp vec4 vPosition;
```

This happened on the iPhone 5 as well as in an iPhone simulator. Strange that this does not yield a statement in the log.

Comment: There is a second log in addition to compile; `glGetProgramInfoLog (...)`. This will give you the log (per-program) for linker errors/warnings, the other log (per-shader) is for compile errors/warnings.